# "Je ne veux pas d'un éléphant dans un boa": why d'un and not un?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, verbes, articles, littérature

> — Non ! Non ! Je ne veux pas d'un éléphant dans un boa. [...]
>
> [ [*The Little Prince*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Prince), Antoine de Saint-Exupéry, 1943 ]

I'm [99%](https://www.google.com/search?q=petit%20prince%20translation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=lFBtVefTGo-SyQSco4CYDQ#tbm=bks&q=editions:3iqYAdChqxkC) sure this means something like "*I don't want an elephant inside a boa*".

What is the purpose of "*d'un*", isn't that "*of an*" as in "*I don't want of an elephant inside a boa*"??

Answer (score 10):

*Ne pas vouloir de* is something of an emphatic construction that specifically rejects a situation that could befall you for some reason, as here, because the Prince is being offered one.

This is why when you answer in the negative to a question with *veux/voulez-vous* [+ objet], the formulation is technically "*Je n'**en** veux pas*", where the *en* implies a phrase with *de*.

When you're saying "*je ne veux pas*" with a following noun phrase, you're usually implying that you want something else, which you're going to promptly explain. The *de* construction specifically rejects the possibility without implying anything further.

Comment: Would it be "less idiomatic" to answer *Oui, j'en veux* to a *veux/voulez-vous* question ? Is the negation really the point ?

Comment: The *de* here is specific to the negative. You'd answer *Oui j'en veux* only if asked, say *Voulez-vous du potage?*. That was only an example. Of course in either case people rarely actually use "vouloir" for themselves (it's a politeness thing, I believe, about not stating one's want explicitly). "Technically", not "normally" is the adverb I want there.

Comment: Do you imply *« Je veux de toi pour épouse. »* ...doesn't exist, or is incorrect ? It seems to me the *de* here is **not** specific to the negative.

Comment: I'm and I hope I don,t sound like I am. To me the question relates mostly to the negative, and the two construction are not used in the same situations.

Comment: So is it more common to respond to such questions with "Oui, j'en veux" or "Oui, je le veux"?

Comment: Neither. The first is outright ungrammatical (the correct form is *j'en veux **un***, but no one actually says that either), the second is only used for the "I do" of marriage.

The proper response is just *oui/non*. The default answer doesn't repeat the verb. Unless you want to add emphasis, it just sounds way over-formal.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm 99% sure this means something like "I don't want an elephant inside a boa".

Not really. I think it means something more like "*I want nothing to do with...*", rather than "*I don't want...*".  It's a **rejection of the entire idea**, not just an expression of not wanting it.  A somewhat more literal translation might be *I want nothing of it* -- the "*of it*" is like the "*d'un*".

Romain & Circeus have answered this well. It's about *vouloir de*, not just *vouloir*.

I'd suggest that equivalent English, for the negation, is something along the lines of your *not wanting to have anything to do with it*.

"*Je ne veux pas d'un elephant dans un boa*" means, essentially, "*I want **nothing to do with** any elephant that is inside a boa*" (or "*I want nothing to do with a boa that has an elephant inside it*").  One might even be inclined to add, "*I don't even want to think about it.*"

Comment: (+1) Very good point about the type of rejection it implies.

Comment: I too like your point and discussion about the added (total) negativity conveyed by “pas de + un” and how it translates nicely (and nearly literally, but for the missing/implied “rien”/”aucun”) to wanting “nothing/none of it.”  Whether or not it’s the same concept, your discussion made me think immediately of the absolute negativity conveyed by “pas de” in the battle cry “[je ne veux ]Pas de ça chez moi !” (Not in my backyard), with ça meaning, of course, “un elephant ….” in this case. +1

Answer (score 5):

There are several meaning nuances for the verb “vouloir”. Here, your case corresponds to this one in Wiktionary :

11. (vouloir de, généralement sous forme négative) Accepter, malgré des conditions ou des conséquences défavorables.

There’s the idea of acceptance and it is mainly use in the case where you refuse a proposal.

Some examples:

- Je veux faire quelque chose = I want to do something
- Je veux un ballon = I want (desir to have) a ballon
- Je ne veux pas un ballon, je veux deux gateaux = I don’t want a ballon, I want two cakes (You are expressing a choice, a decision. In this context, after having said what you don’t want, you often say in addition what you do want. It can be another quantity or something else instead, or both something else and in another quantity)
- Je ne veux pas d’un ballon, garde-le ! = I don’t want a ballon, keep it! (This is used in the case you refuse a proposal. The contracted version of the same sentence would be: Je n'en veux pas, garde-le ! = I don’t want it, keep it!)

PS : Dans ton cas, l'auteur donne au Petit Prince un dessin et ce dernier n'est pas content, il refuse le dessin et dit qu'il n'en veut pas.

Answer (score 4):

It is one of the different possible constructions for the verb *vouloir*.
(which is indeed one of these overused verbs which have a huge number of meanings and constructions)

**Vouloir de [X]** means "accepter [X]", which slightly differs from the main meaning of the verb. It is therefore used only to refer to something *after it has been proposed to someone*. Example : *"Depuis une heure je lui explique que c'est plein de vitamines mais elle n'en veut pas !"*

It can also be used to refer to someone rather than something, and sometimes it's an implied reference to wedding proposal. As in :

> « Je te construirai un chateau si tu veux de moi ! »

More on this subject in the TLFi article [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir) (II, A)