# "Vouloir de quelque chose" ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

In the song *Ce Jeu* by Yelle, one line goes "Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille," which I understand to mean "I don't want a flawless love." However, the *vouloir de* is confusing to me. I've never seen that with a noun before.

Why isn't it simply "*Je ne veux pas un amour sans faille*"? Why is *de* needed here?

Comment: I don't know if it is _needed_ - both with and without sound ok to me.

Comment: In that case my question becomes, when is *de* optional after *vouloir* and when is it entirely inappropriate?

Comment: Except for cases like _vouloir la soupe/vouloir de la soupe_,  
my best guess is that it boils down to usage.

Comment: See http://french.stackexchange.com/q/13980/1109

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The preposition *de* is optional here and adds a nuance: It strengthens the refusal and possibly link it to an implicit or explicit object or concept for which the refusal is specifically motivated.

Depending on the context, telling that the particular object you have been offered is not of your taste might be considered rude.

> *Je ne veux pas ta voiture.* I don't want your car (neutral).

> *Je ne veux pas de ta voiture.* I really don't want your car, I don't want to use it specifically. (unfriendly)

---

> *Je ne veux pas de voiture.* No car please (don't try to propose a car to me).

> *Je ne veux pas une voiture.* I don't want a car but I'm looking for something else.

> *Je ne veux pas d'une voiture.* The car you were thinking of doesn't suit my needs at all.

---

> *Je ne veux pas un appartement au rez-de-chaussée.* (stating a requirement) → I'm not looking for an apartment at the ground-floor, but I'm open for something else, possibly an upper stairs apartment.

> *Je ne veux pas d'appartement au rez-de-chaussée.* (stating a requirement) → I'm not looking for an apartment at the ground-floor, and I'm possibly not looking for any apartment.

> *Je ne veux pas d'un appartement au rez-de-chaussée.* (You have been proposed a ground floor apartment) → I don't want at all a ground-floor apartment, I wouldn't have use of the one you are thinking of.

---

> Je ne veux pas un amour sans faille. (Simple statement about personal preferences: a perfect love is not what I'm looking for but I'm likely still looking for love)

> Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille. (This sentence is replying to a possibly unexpressed but implicit proposal for a perfect love, I refuse that perfect love you proposed to me)

References :

1. ["Leçons de linguistique de Gustave Guillaume, 1945-1946"](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Fkq2kxxoXpUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). It contains a comprehensive discussion about the difference between ***je ne veux pas un livre***, ***je ne veux pas de livre***, and ***je ne veux pas d'un livre***.

   On page 155, it is stated:

   > ***Ne pas vouloir d'un livre** signifie : estimer, juger que, parmi un ensemble de livres envisagé, il y a **un** livre faisant l'objet d'un refus motivé, d'une exclusion spéciale. **Ne pas vouloir de** ajoute ainsi au sens simple **ne pas vouloir** quelque chose qui lui vient du mot **de** agissant partie comme préposition et partie comme adverbe.*

   and on page 158:

   > ***Je ne veux pas un livre** signifie implicitement : « J'ai un autre vouloir, je désire autre chose.» Par exemple : « Pour mon anniversaire, je ne voudrais pas un livre, je voudrait qu'on m'offrît autre chose. » On a affaire à un vouloir négatif assez incomplet pour suggérer le complément d'un vouloir positif.
   >
   > La nuance est sujette à varier assez sensiblement avec le contexte, mais toujours on a une négation qui, non totale, retrouve la totalité —  la complétude —  en se donnant secrètement un complément dans l'ordre du positif.*
2. [*Manuel de la grammaire française*, Gabriel Wyler](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319222529/http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page020.html) (archive):

   > Dans *goûtez de ce vin*, la valeur grammaticale de *de ce vin* est la même que celle de *ce vin*. La préposition *de* ajoute une nuance sémantique à *ce vin* (l'idée de puiser, d'extraire, de prélever), mais laisse son caractère nominal intact. L'expression *de ce vin* est l'objet direct de *goûtez*.

Comment: @Aerovistae - here is the reaction of another French native on the same topic: "Je ne veux pas de ta pitié est plus fort que je ne veux pas ta pitié : le "de" est de valeur affective. Il met à distance (rejet) le mot "pitié".
Ceci pour la forme négative.
Pour la forme affirmative :
Je veux bien de ton amitié diffère de je veux bien ton amitié pour la même raison : le "de" distingue cette fois-ci le mot "amitié". C'est encore un "de" affectif."

Comment: @Aerovistae I would appreciate it if you and others would tell this Frank to stop making comments about me. And saying I am "propagating falsehoods about the French language". I tried to have a reasoned discussion with him and he just keeps changing the rules of his game. The CNTRL definitions show that the two are not the same in black and white and IN FRENCH. Ergo, their translations must DIFFER.  And my Translations to help Aerovistae aimed to show that: nothing more.

Comment: What is the material difference between "je ne veux pas cette voiture" and "je ne veux pas de cette voiture"? In the end, you don't want that car. That is all there is to it. This business about "nothing to do with" or relationship with the car, or using the car ... is IMHO fake, and does not really change the meaning of the sentence. There is a given car. You don't want it. Having _de_ in this case does not materially change the meaning of the sentence in my opinion.

Comment: @Frank Of course it could. I'm describing nuances so both forms do implicitly overlap. My point is the expressions are not strictly identical, and this opinion seems to be shared so far by the majority of voters here.

Comment: @Frank The difference is very clear to me with the car example. They overlap (both refuse the car) but the first sentence is neutral while the second one is rude.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53090/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-vouloir-de-quelque-chose).

Answer (score 10):

**Vouloir is want**, **ne pas vouloir de** means: to not want something of, or to not want to have anything to do with. The difference in meaning comes through in translation. I am not commenting here "on the French"; only on the difference in meaning as can be seen in translating it.

Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille.

I want nothing to do with perfect love. [sans faille means without any defects, i.e., perfect].

Je ne veux pas cette voiture. I don't want that car.

Je ne veux pas de cette voiture. I want nothing to do with/I don't want anything to do with that car.

Comment: Is this useful? The question is: what is the difference, in French, between "Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille." and "Je ne veux pas un amour sans faille."? What is your take on that?

Comment: J'ai expliqué la différence. ne pas vouloir x et ne pas vouloir avoir un rapport quelconque avec x, ne rien savoir d'elle. Mais il me semble tout à fait légitime de montrer la différence par la traduction puisque la personne parle anglais.

Comment: Oui mais cette explication est fausse. Elle ne tient pas la route dans le cas de "Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille." et "Je ne veux pas un amour sans faille.". Dans les deux cas, la personne ne veut simplement rien avoir à faire avec l'amour de l'autre.

Comment: Ne pas vouloir un rapport a un object (sujet) n'est pas ne pas vouloir  un objet, même si les deux impliquent l'absence de l'objet. Et si c'était pareil il n'y aurait pas de différence au moment de traduire les deux phrases. Donc, ce n'est pas faux. Et ce qui est vrai, c'est que vous ne cherchez pas la petite bête du bon côté.

Comment: correction: objet

Answer (score 3):

'Je ne veux pas un amour sans faille' présente ou rappelle le type d'amour que l'on ne veut pas par opposition à d'autres types d'amour possibles.

Exemple: Tu n'as rien compris! Je ne veux pas un amour sans faille! Ce n'est pas ce que j'ai voulu dire! Je veux un amour solide / libre / exclusif...

Par contre dans 'Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille' "de" est utilisé parce que 'un amour sans faille' a été choisi à l'exclusion de tout autre type d'amour comme sujet de réflexion avant la production de cet énoncé.

Dit autrement:

1-La personne qui parle réfléchit à ce qu'est "un amour sans faille" ou est confrontée à l'idée de "un amour sans faille" à l'exclusion de tout autre type d'amour.

2-Elle décide de refuser ce type d'amour.

3- Dans la mise en phrase 'Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille', les séquences 1 et 2 sont inversées. "DE" est la trace de cette inversion. La séquence 1 servant à bloquer, comme thème du discours, le choix de "un amour sans faille", à l'exclusion de toute autre possibilité. C'est de cela dont on parle et pas d'autre chose.

Pour 'Le parti ne veut pas d'un Poincaré à l'Elysée' :

1- Il est question de choisir Poincaré pour l'Elysée.

2- Le parti réagit à cette hypothèse à l'exclusion de toute autre: Il ne veut pas de ce choix.

3- La mise en phrase inverse ces deux séquences et DE apparaît, soulignant ainsi que le moment du choix de Poincaré parmi d'autres avait été dépassé.

Answer (score 2):

[TLF][1] recognizes a transitive direct usage of the verb *vouloir*, as well as a transitive *indirect* usage (with "de"). The transitive indirect form is given as more usually used in negative sentences.

There are "easy" cases where *de* indicates *a part of* only:

> Je veux la soupe. (all of it)
>
> Je veux *de* la soupe. (some of it will be enough)

In this case, the difference in meaning justifies the use of *de*. If you don't want the *whole soup*, but only some of it, you *have* to use *de*.

There are also many cases of negations where *de* is required:

> Je ne veux pas de lui dans mon équipe.
>
> <strike>Je ne veux pas lui dans mon équipe.</strike> (incorrect)
>
> Je ne le veux pas dans mon équipe. (mandatory if not using *de*)
>
> Je n'en veux pas dan mon équipe. (most commonly used?)

But is *de* always required in negations?

Let's try the pair:

> Je ne veux pas *de* cette voiture.
>
> Je ne veux pas cette voiture.

where the car is not divisible in parts like soup. In this case, it is hard to perceive any real difference in meaning, and it seems that *de* can be included or left out. The meaning does not seem to drive the usage of *de*. there is a given car. You don't want it. There is not much more going on here.

In the example posted by the OP, *where IMHO both forms are possible*:

> Je ne veux pas d'un amour sans faille.
>
> Je ne veux pas un amour sans faille.

I cannot feel much difference in meaning either. The first sentence flows better than the second one, maybe. But these two sentences actually say the exact same thing, so here again, meaning does not seem to be the driver for the usage of *de*. Let's take another example:

> Je ne veux pas ton amour.
>
> Je ne veux pas de ton amour.

It is again hard to pinpoint the actual difference between these two sentences. The first one maybe feels more direct, and therefore stronger (?), but that is IMHO questionable. You can also make a case that in the second version, you only want *part* of the love the person, but that does not feel like it is necessarily the case.

Third example:

> Le parti ne veut pas de Poincaré à l'Élysée (Aragon, Beaux quart., 1936, p. 203)

Is that *de* required? No:

> Le parti ne veut pas Poincaré à l'Élysée.

has the same meaning in the end, except maybe that this last sentence is more direct. The first one also feels more natural. The second one is IMHO grammatically correct. The *meaning* is the same.

One more:

> Vouloir de Mlle X pour épouse (Caput 1969).

Is there anything wrong or different if we remove that *de*?

> Vouloir Mlle X pour épouse.

Not really. Here, using *de* might be more idiomatic. But retracting that *de* does not materially change the meaning of the sentence.

So, from these examples, beyond cases of divisibles things and negations where it is required, there is number of cases where it does not look like the addition or removal of *de* makes much difference at all. The choice of using *de* or not would not *always* be driven by the meaning of the sentence.

In conclusion, *de* is required to indicate that you want only a part of the thing you want, there are many cases of negations where *de* is grammatically required (but maybe not all), and then there are many cases (of negations) where it makes very little difference in meaning, except that inserting *de* feels more natural.

Comment: Its presence in negatives could be linked with "il y a" + nom vs. "il n'y a pas" + de + nom, though the presence of the article in @Aerovistae's example weakens the parallel a little.

Comment: Ok but you aren't explaning the nuance between *vouloir* and *vouloir de*.

Comment: @Gilles - correct, because I can't, and I think in fact that there is no real difference, besides usage. TLF does not make to seem a big difference either. The post below is wrong, and the nuance that Lambie puts in her  English translation is actually not present in French, as far as I can tell.

Comment: *Vouloir* and *vouloir de* are not interchangeable. There is definitely a nuance. For example, you can say “je ne veux pas forcément une réponse complète” but it wouldn't work with *de*. Sometimes it's even grammatical, e.g. “je ne veux pas de lui dans mon équipe” can't be used without *de*.

Comment: Correct - there are expressions where one or the other is indicated. But the point is to find a rationale for when _de_ is required. I can't find one beyond usage, once we have adjudicated the case of _vouloir la soupe/vouloir de la soupe_.

Comment: @Gilles Since they are different, they have to be translated into English differently. That was what my answer was about.

Comment: @Gilles - sometimes, they are interchangeable actually. Sometimes they are not. I try to give examples of both in my response. The real difficulty is what happens when they are both possible.

Comment: What about *Je n'en veux pas dans mon équipe* which seems closer to your *Je ne veux pas de lui dans mon équipe*?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my list. It is probably the most common, in fact, but we are farther and farther from the discussion of using _de_ or not _de_, which is why I hadn't added it at first. But thanks for the suggestion.