# Ils ne veulent pas de moi

Tags: prépositions, négation

I have listened the following sentence in a movie:

Ils ne veulent pas de moi dans l'équipe.

Why is "de moi" used instead of "me"? Why is there a "de" before "moi"? I know "de" replaces an indefinite article/partitive article before a *noun* in a direct object when the sentence is negative, but "moi" is a pronoun, so this must be the effect of another grammar rule.

AFAIK, the same does not happen with most other verbs in negative sentences, neither with "vouloir" in affirmative sentences. For instance:

- Ils ne m'embauchent pas.
- Ils me veulent dans l'équipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the verb is not "vouloir" but "vouloir de qqn" ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir));

> (TLFi) A. − [Le plus souvent à la forme nég.] Vouloir de
>    1. Vouloir de qqn. *Être disposé à recevoir, à accepter quelqu'un. Ne plus vouloir de qqn.* (user **LPH**'s italics)

The use of this verb has a particularity; you don't use it much in the affirmative form, mostly only  the negative  or with the conjunction "si", or, other possibility, when the verb is modified by an adverb;

- Nous ne voulons pas d'eux dans les cérémonies.
- Il ne veulent d'elle que lorsque elle apporte de la bière.
- S'ils veulent de vous vous aurez de la chance.
- S'ils veulent de lui, eh bien il ira à l'entrainement.
- Le patron veut bien d'elle comme assistante, mais il a un caractère si spécial qu'elle ne le supportera pas. (*not any adverb: "bien", "certainement"…*)

There is another form: "qqn vouloir qqn"; this one accounts for the sentence "Ils me veulent dans l'équipe." ;

> A. − [Le suj. désigne une pers.]
>   1. Avoir la ferme intention, le souhait, le désir de

d) [Le compl. d'obj. dir. désigne une pers.]
 Qqn veut qqn. Rome veut un maître.

This verb is used normally, that is both in the affirmative and the negative forms.

Comment: The TLFi definition really downplays the condescension of 'vouloir de'.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Vous voulez dire « condescendance, comme au TLFi: Attitude dédaigneuse, méprisante envers quelqu'un.   ex. Je ne veux pas de ces gens-là sur ma propriété. » ? En effet, le TLFi n'entre pas dans ces détails. Quelqu'un capture bien cette idée dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/24549/17649).

Answer (score 3):

This *de* is not an article but a preposition here and used in the indirect transitive form *vouloir de* while *vouloir* alone is direct transitive.

*Vouloir de* is not necessarily used in negative sentences:

> Ils me veulent dans l'équipe.

can be rephrased, with a slight change in meaning, as:

> Ils veulent de moi dans l'équipe.

and reciprocally:

> Ils ne veulent pas de moi dans l'équipe.

as

> Il ne me veulent pas dans l'équipe.

See also, more about *ne pas vouloir de*: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/24555/1109

Comment: The link you mentioned says that "vouloir de" adds an idea of of "puiser, extraire, prélever" (= withdrawing, extracting, taking). I have not understood what this means exactly. Could you explain better?

Comment: Here is an attempt to explain the difference: *Il me veulent dans l'équipe*: They (really) want me in the team while *ils veulent de moi dans l'équipe*: they want (or just accept) to have "my person" in the team.