# Can you say 'elle ne veut pas d'une extension' ?

Tags: de

I came across this in a news report: 'La Russie ne veut pas d'une extension de l'OTAN vers l'est'. Is this correct usage? I thought after 'ne ... pas' you would write 'de' instead of 'une', not in addition to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Vouloir de quelque chose" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24546/vouloir-de-quelque-chose) vouloir de quelque chose and vouloir quelque chose do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb phrase "vouloir de qqc" is the form used in this sentence, and it is different in meaning from  "vouloir qqc".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir))
> **II. − Empl. trans. indir.**
> **A. − [Le plus souvent à la forme nég.] Vouloir de**
> **2. Vouloir de qqc.** [Souvent dans une phrase nég.] **Être disposé à prendre, à accepter, à recevoir, à garder quelque chose.**
> ♦ Ne vouloir de qqc. pour rien au monde.
> ♦ L'avenir m'effraye tant, que je ne veux pas de l'avenir, et le présent m'est insupportable (Balzac, Illus. perdues, 1843, p. 698).
> ♦ Vous avez tant de mérites réels, que vous devez être le premier à ne pas vouloir d'un mérite factice (Hugo, Corresp., 1862, p. 376).

Whereas "vouloir qqc" (**I. − Empl. trans. dir. A. − [Le suj. désigne une pers.] 1. Avoir la ferme intention, le souhait, le désir de.
a) Empl. abs. Avoir de la volonté, faire preuve de volonté.**) is used to express someone's will, "vouloir de qqc" is used to express rather someone's lack of disposition towards something.

Notice the following variants (different meanings); they are grammatically correct uses of the verb form in "**I**".

- La Russie ne veut pas d'extension de l'OTAN vers l'est. (*vouloir qqc*)
- La Russie ne veut pas une extension de l'OTAN vers l'est. (*vouloir qqc*)

This form is not used in  affirmative statements, only in negative ones except in some sentences such as hypothetical clauses and perhaps in other less important contexts.

*Examples of use in non négative statements (hypothetical constructions)*

- S'ils avaient voulu d'un arrangement équitable il aurait déjà été conclu.
- Auraient-ils voulu de cet arrangement, nous l'aurions considéré comme une bonne solution.

Comment: @jlliagre Je dois admettre que cette construction est assez rarement utilisée, mais sa logique me parait inattaquable ; on trouve [l'exemple suivant](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Coup_d_%C3%89tat_du_18_brumaire_et_ses_co/OoA5DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22si+j%27avais+voulu+d%27+un%22&pg=PT14&printsec=frontcover), « Citoyens, si j'avais voulu d'un tel rôle, il m'était facile de le prendre au retour d'Italie, et lorsque l'armée et les partis m'invitaient à m'en emparer ; ». (1/3)

Comment: @jlliagre  Il y a aussi celui-ci, « Quelqu'un lui ayant demandé s'il voulait d'un roi papiste, il dit, qu'il ne savait que répondre à cette objection ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Causes_C%C3%A9l%C3%A8bres_%C3%89trang%C3%A8res_Publi%C3%A9es/rkhjAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22s%27il+voulait+d%27un%22&pg=PA50&printsec=frontcover)),  (2/3)

Comment: @jlliagre  et encore cet autre (2017), « Je ne voulais pas vivre avec des suppositions, et des doutes, s'il voulait d'un nous, si je voulais d'un nous, il ne fallait plus qu'il y ait de secrets,… » ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Caf%C3%A9_in_partie_1/u7Z3DgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22s%27il+voulait+d%27un%22&pg=PT207&printsec=frontcover)). (3/3)

Comment: Tu peux tout supprimer comme moi, il s'agissait d'un malentendu.